# Fluttere, the last page I closed appears instantly when I open a new page

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-getx

When I switch between pages in the drawer, the previous page appears for 1 second, then it closes and the page I want appears.
https://youtube.com/shorts/YS5P2aQLBAM?feature=share

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          //Drawer Header
          //Drawer Body
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                drawerItem(context, () {
                  Get.to(() => ProfileScreen());
                }, "Hesabım", Icons.person),
                drawerItem(context, () {
                  Get.to(() => MyAdress());
                }, "Adreslerim", Icons.location_on_sharp),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  GestureDetector drawerItem(
      BuildContext context, VoidCallback onTap, String? a, IconData icon) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(icon, color: Colors.black54),
        title: Text(
          a.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that will reproduce the same error.

Comment: Hello, I made the addition you said.

Comment: Sorry I dont know about getx, try to check if the child is calling Navigator pop directly

Comment: Same thing happens when I use material page route instead of getx navigation

Answer (score 0):

Try the below thing:

On the tap of drawerItem first, close the `Drawer` by `Navigator.pop(context);` than move to the next screen.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work